# How to prevent state param being encrypted in Identity Server OIDC

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect, .net-6.0

I am using Identity Server 4 to forward authorize requests on to an external IdP.

I can see the browser making this request:

```
    https://externalIdp.com/OpenIdConnect/Forward
    ?$authorize_url=https://authorizeUrl.com/oauth2/v1/authorize
    &$interstitial_prompt_company_client_id=true
    &$interstitial_tryGetClientIdFromCookie=true
    &client_id=1oa1ml149rjc2sybG0h8
    &redirect_uri=https://localhost:44349/Account/ExternalIdPCallback
    &response_type=code
    &scope=openid profile
    &code_challenge=6FDCh_IfSkBrjhC4KnyX7FBSCH4pWxshYvRuLQ0AXNM
    &code_challenge_method=S256
    &response_mode=form_post
    &nonce=<nonce>
    &state=CfDJ8LuOVczCdnBOlV1ujnRXX...
    &x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0
    &x-client-ver=6.8.0.0
```

I believe the value for the `state` param in this URL comes from the `Items` property in:

```
var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(AccountController.ExternalIdPCallback));
var provider = "oidc";
var props = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = callbackUrl,
    Items =
    {
        { "scheme", provider },
        { "returnUrl", returnUrl }
    }
};
return Challenge(props, provider);
```

Here's my `Startup.ConfigureServices()`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = "Cookies";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "oidc";
})
.AddCookie("Cookies")
.AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", "CentralIdentity", options =>
{
    options.CallbackPath = "/Account/ExternalIdPCallback";
    options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
    options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    
    options.Authority = "https://externalIdp.com";
    options.ClientId = "1oa1ml149rjc2sybG0h8";
    options.ClientSecret = "ClientSecretHere";
    options.ResponseType = "code";
    options.ResponseMode = "form_post";
    options.AuthenticationMethod = OpenIdConnectRedirectBehavior.RedirectGet;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        RoleClaimType = "role"
    };
});
```

My IdP requires that the `state` param value be in clear text.

How can I prevent the `state` param value from being encrypted?